# Evaluate Collaborative-Filtering

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm at the end of my project and my company asked me to evalute the model without metrics. In brief, after obtaing the best 10 reccomendation, I should see if these reccomandation are between the movies that the new user wanted to see. I don't understand how I can do it if I'm doing and algorithm for prediction these movies.

Slowly, I've found a possibile ansewer to my question. A user said that a possibile approach could be  hide a few data points at random for every user, make recommendations using your algorithm, and then uncover the hidden data and see how many of those matched the recommendations.

But I still don't have clear ideas. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do evaluation:

1. Filter the users who have more than 20 ratings with value 5 (the exact numbers will depend on your dataset);
2. Randomly select two movies per user;

That’s our test set — it won’t be used during the training, but these movies should appear in the top recommendations for selected users accordingly.

You can find more details and practical implementation in the article about [building recommendation system based Bayesian Personalized Ranking](https://medium.com/heyjobs-tech/building-recommendation-system-based-bayesian-personalized-ranking-using-tensorflow-2-1-b814d2704130).